# How to export Enterprise Architect diagram links to csv using python?

Tags: python, enterprise-architect

I want to export Enterprise Architect model relation links to CSV file.

I'm doing it using python in given way.

```py
import win32com.client

def ea():
    try:
        eaApp = win32com.client.Dispatch('EA.App')
        eaRep = eaRep.Repository
    except:
        sys.exit()
    try:
        eaRep.OpenFile2("C:\\path-to-model.eap", 1, 0)
        package_guid = "{ABC34Hs-*****}"
        dia = eaRep.getDiagramByGUID(package_guid)

        res = eaRep.SQLQuery(f"select * from t_diagram where ea_guid = '{package_guid}'")
        print(res)

        for do in dia.diagramobjects:
            elem = eaRep.getElementByID(do.elementId)
            if elem.name == "my-diagram":
                print(elem.Name, elem.Type, do.left, do.right, do.top)
            print(elem.Notes)
    except:
        pass

ea()
```

Here I'm only getting model diagram details like geometry points some more info like Package-ID, Diagram-Id, Type etc.

1. How can we extract all relation links of model to CSV/Excel file using Python?
2. Is Python a really good language preference for EA links exporting work? as I could no see well maintained documentation for `win32com.client`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "relation links of model", but if you are talking about the relations, then you'll want to check the `t_connector` table.

That table contains the relationship details, including the Object_ID's of both the source as target element.

Since the EA repository is a database the easiest way to get to the information you need is to use a query.

```
select os.Name as StartElement, c.Name, c.Connector_Type
, c.Stereotype, ot.Name as TargetElement
from ((t_connector c
inner join t_object os on os.Object_ID = c.Start_Object_ID)
inner join t_object ot on ot.Object_ID = c.End_Object_ID)
```

You haven't specified what information you needed from the connectors, so I added a few columns as illustration.

When you pass that through `Repository.SQLQuery` you'll get an XML string that you can parse with an XML library.

I guess Python is as good as any other language.
My personal preferences for dealing with EA are C# and VBScript

Comment: Thanks! It's working now. I would also like to know about how we can get relationships of perticular diagram or package using GUID or package ID?

Comment: For diagram join t_diagramlinks. For package, check the packageID of the source or target element (or both depending on your needs)

Comment: If the attribute of class A is linked with the attribute of class B and then to class C attribute. Then I need all relationship combinations in row manner. Which will be CSV file. Is there any way to get such data using SQL query?

Comment: @AkashPagar yes. **All** model info is stored in the database, so you can definitely get it with the right SQL query.

Answer (score 2):

To amend Geerts answer with the according operation:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def query(self, sql):
    root = ET.fromstring(self.eaRep.SQLQuery (sql))
    data = root.getchildren()
    if len(data) == 0: return []
    ds = data[0][0]
    rows = []
    for row in ds:
        cols = []
        for col in row.getchildren(): cols.append(col.text)
        rows.append(cols)
    return rows
```

Here `self.eaRep` is your `eaRep` since the above is used in my own wrapper class for the repository. Returns the result as array of array.

Regarding Python: rest assured. I use it since many years. The win32 stuff isn't well documented, yes, but once you get the handle (and that's pretty easy in almost all cases) you don't have to worry any more about that.

Comment: eaRep.OpenFile2("C:\\path-to-model.eap", 1, 0). Is this statement reading whole eap file? What are the arguments 1 and 0? Asking this because I 'm not able to go into the source code of OpenFile2() method while debugging in IDE.

Comment: @AkashPagar Ask Sparx. I have no insight into their code.